# Como insertar checkbox dentro de mi tabla mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una tabla de solicitudes y lo que quiero hacer es un `UPDATE` que cuando marque el `checkbox` de varias de ellas se me actualice la base de datos que todas las seleccionadas están en ruta.

Me lanza un error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login18\Login\vista\checkruta.php on line 15
>   Data Inserted Successfully!

```
    <form action="checkruta.php" method="post" >
        <table class="my-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Folio</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Fecha Solicitud</th>
                    <th>Solicitud</th>
                    <th>Estado</th>
                    <th>Fecha reporte</th>
                    <th>Seleccionar Ruta</th> 
                    <th><input type="submit" name="guardar" value="guardar"/></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            {
                $id=$row[0];
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row[0];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[1];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[6];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[7];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[8];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[10];?></td> 
                    <?php echo "<td><input type='checkbox' id='cbox1' name='rutas[]' value='<?php echo $row[0];?>'> <br></td>";?>
            </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="table-pagination pull-right">
        <?php echo paginate($reload, $page, $total_pages, $adjacents);?>
        </div>
    </form>
<?php
} 
else 
{
?>
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4>Aviso!!!</h4> No hay datos para mostrar
</div>
<?php
\\Codigo de insercion
<?php
    extract($_POST);
    $server = "localhost";
    $usuario = "root";
    $contraseña = "";
    $bd = "bdpagina";

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $contraseña, $bd)
    or die("error en la conexion");
    if( !empty( $_POST[ 'rutas' ] ) ) 
    {
        foreach( $_POST[ 'rutas' ] as $ruta ) 
        {
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bdpagina");
            $query="UPDATE contribuyente SET ruta = '$ruta' WHERE contribuyente. id = '$row[0]'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            echo "Data Inserted Successfully!";
            echo $ruta; 
        }
    }
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hay Danielita, tu codigo es muy dificil de entender si no tienes la indentacion adecuada.

Comment: Tu codigo es ambiguo.  Creo que el else se ejecuta cuando $numrows <= 0.  La variable `$row` no esta definida en el else.